# Changing android actionbar background not working

Tags: android, colors, background, tabs, android-actionbar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```

I'm trying to change my actionbar and the tab backgrounds, using the code above, the actionbar background changes perfectly but the tab backgrounds doesn't change at all, I'd like to know if this is due to the fact that I use supportActionBar or not, if anyone has a solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easier to use it via xml.

have you tried out the next links:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

?

Comment: yes, in fact I'm using the style generator and I think it is the correct way to do it but making the code above work just became something like a personal issue and I really want to know why the first line works and the second one doesn't, but thanks for the quick and correct response!

Comment: ok. i'm not sure how to do it. btw, for color, you could simply use 0x330000ff instead of parsing a string of "#330000ff"